# Angular Material Dialog: resolver with data?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible add a resolver to angular material dialog so that some data can be pre-loaded before the actual dialog is loaded?

PS: I don't need to open the dialog from the url, but on a click of a button.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is nothing special about this:

1) HTML:
`(click)="onClickOpenDialog()"`

2) TS

```
onClickOpenDialog() {
  this.myService.getMyData().subscribe(receivedData => {
    let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
      data: { myData: receivedData },
    });
  });
```

3) Your dialog:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: '...',
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public myData: any) { }
}
```

Comment: You are injecting data through the ref which is the usual way. I want to do it through a route resolver.

Comment: Your dialog is not handled by the router, sounds odd to do it this way... Maybe you can tell us more about why you need this to be handled by the router ? An other solution would be to use a communication service.